# Opengl hide parts of the screen

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

(code snippet. I know it's ugly but i wanted to make it work before making it better so please don't pay too much attention to the structure)

I modified slightly the glfw example present in the documentation to have a triangle that rotates when pressing the right arrow key and draws a circle described by the position of one of his  vertices (the blue one in this case).
I clear the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` only when initializing the window to avoid having to store all the coordinates that will be needed to draw the line (they would be hundreds of thousands in the final program), that means that on the screen every time i press the right arrow a "copy" of the triangle is draws rotated by 12 degrees and a line is drawn that connects the old blue angle position to the new one.

The problem now is that i would want to be able to press the escape key `GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE` and "delete" the triangles while keeping the lines drawn.

I tried using a z-buffer to hide the triangles behind a black rectangle but only the last line drawn is visualized (i think this is because opengl doesn't know the z of the previous lines since i don't store them).

Is there a way to do what i want without having to store all the point coordinates and then clearing the whole screen and redrawing only the lines? If this is the case, what would be the best way to store them?

Here is part of the code i have so far.

```
bool check = 0;

Vertex blue = {0.f, 0.6f, 0.5f};
Vertex green = {0.6f,-0.4f, 0.5f};
Vertex red = {-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.5f};
Vertex line = {0.f, 0.6f, 0.f};
Vertex line2 = {0.f, 0.6f, 0.f};

static void
key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        check = !check;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        line.x = line2.x;
        line.y = line2.y;
        rotation -= 12;
        rad = DegToRad(-12);
        double x = line.x*cos(rad) - line.y * sin(rad);
        double y = line.y * cos(rad) + line.x * sin(rad);
        line2.x = x;
        line2.y = y;
}

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow *window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(rotation, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(red.x, red.y, red.z);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(green.x, green.y, green.z);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(blue.x, blue.y, blue.z);
        glEnd();

        glLoadIdentity();
        glLineWidth(1.0);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(line.x, line.y, line.z);
        glVertex3f(line2.x, line2.y, line2.z);
        glEnd();

        if (check){
            //hide the triangles but not the lines
         }

        glEnd();


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to draw a wireframe?

Comment: @Bartvbl my intention would be to draw a spirograph, for simplicity i was starting from a simple triangle that draws a circle and the expanding it once i can get it to work correctly

Comment: So why don't you saw with lines instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I clear the GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT only when initializing the window

That's your problem right there. It's idiomatic in OpenGL to always start with a clear operation of the main framebuffer color bits. That is, because you don't know the state of your window main framebuffer when the operating system is asking for a redraw. For all you know it could have been all replaced with cat pictures in the background without your program knowing it. Seriously: If you have a cat video running and the OS felt the need to rearrange your window's main framebuffer memory this is what you might end up with.

> Is there a way to do what i want without having to store all the point coordinates and then clearing the whole screen and redrawing only the lines?

For all intents and purposes: No. In theory one could come up with a contraption made out of a convoluted series of stencil buffer operations to implement that, but this would be barking up a very wrong tree.

Here's something for you to try out: Draw a bunch of triangles like you do, then resize your window down so there nothing remains, then resize it back to its original size… you see where the problem? There's a way to address this particular problem, but that's not what you should do here.

The correct thing is to redraw everything. If you feel that that's to slow you have to optimize your drawing process. On current generation hardware it's possible to churn out on the order of 100 million triangles per second.

Comment: Ok thanks, i guess that i was searching for confirmation that it couldn't be done "easily" to not keep thinking about this problem xD